# XSLT 1.0 - cancel file create

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

is it posible with XSLT to cancel generating xml-file, if some ceck contains a specific value.

e.g. If InvoiceType = CreditNote, than the system has to do nothing.
-> There should be no output - no xml.

Best regards
Julian

Comment: XSLT does not generate a file. It produces an XML (or HTML or text) document. If you make the condition early enough in the process, then the resulting document will be empty. Creating an actual file (or not) is done by the calling application.

Comment: thanks, but i can´t do this with my application. so my idea was to solve my problem with xslt.

so, i just can create an empty file with xslt, but not stopping processing a xml-document, right?

Comment: As I said, XSLT has no control over what happens after the transformation is done. You **can** abort the transformation process at **any** point using `xsl: message` - but what happens to the contents of the output written so far (including an empty result) is entirely up to the calling application.

Comment: all clear, thx!

Comment: can i edit my question with my xml and can you help me with the correct xslt or should i open a new question?

Comment: I see you have already.